# How to show a message with icon in the notification area

Tags: c#

I am writing code in which if updates are available then I want to show a pop up message with balloon using C#. This is similar to "Java Updates available".

[image: Balloon tool tip]

With the help of the `NotifyIcon` class and the `BalloonTipIcon`  property, I can show the icon in the notification area but not this type of message. Any suggestions will be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the correct output as desired with the below code.

```
notifyIcon1.Visible = true;
notifyIcon1.Icon = SystemIcons.Exclamation;
notifyIcon1.BalloonTipTitle = "Balloon Tip Title";
notifyIcon1.BalloonTipText = "Balloon Tip Text.";
notifyIcon1.BalloonTipIcon = ToolTipIcon.Error;
notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(1000);
```

Thanks @Bhushan for your suggestion....

Comment: I put your exact code to the `Form1_Load` function, but it does not work. No Ballon shows after I start the program, only the icon and nothing happens on click. Of course I already created notifyIcon1

Answer (score 15):

You can use `NotifyIcon` for this.

```
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;  
notifyIcon.BalloonTipIcon = ToolTipIcon.Info;
notifyIcon.BalloonTipTitle = "Notify Icon Test Application";
notifyIcon.BalloonTipText = "You have just minimized the application." + 
                            Environment.NewLine + 
                            "Right-click on the icon for more options.";

notifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip(5000);
```

This will generate popup like one as below:

[image]

You can find more details on [this link](http://www.daveoncsharp.com/2009/08/add-notify-icon-to-system-tray/).

Comment: I am really sorry but it is not solving my purpose. I did gave it a try earlier also but I am getting this pop up in notification area.

Comment: @Arti So where do you want your popup to appear?

Comment: @Arti Your question also says that you want the popup in notification?

Comment: In the notification area as shown in the image. Using above code I am getting the icon but not the image with text in it.

Comment: notifyIcon1.Visible = true;
notifyIcon1.Icon = SystemIcons.Exclamation;
notifyIcon1.BalloonTipTitle = "Balloon Tip Title";
notifyIcon1.BalloonTipText = "Balloon Tip Text.";
notifyIcon1.BalloonTipIcon = ToolTipIcon.Error;

This is what I am writting in the code.

Comment: @Arti You may try this link[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon.aspx]

Answer (score 2):

There is a very simple single-line command you can write for this, instead of doing all that bulky thing others suggest:

```
notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(1000, "Text", "Title", ToolTipIcon.Warning);
```

Remember that you need to have first initialized the control in your application so that this code works. You are free to adjust the control's name and the command's parameters according to your needs.

Comment: Does not work at all for me. Tried it on windows 10.