# Taskbar notification not working: C#

Tags: c#, notifications

I'm new to C#. I want to write a program to display a simple notification. After googling and seeing few stackoverflow answers, I finally wrote a program. But its not working.

Code:

```
public class SysTrayApp : Form
{
    [STAThread]
    public static void Main()
    {
        Application.Run(new SysTrayApp());

    }

    private NotifyIcon trayIcon;
    private ContextMenu trayMenu;

    public SysTrayApp()
    {

        trayMenu = new ContextMenu(); // Create a simple tray menu with only one item.
        trayMenu.MenuItems.Add("Exit", OnExit);

        trayIcon = new NotifyIcon();
        trayIcon.Text = "MyTrayApp";
        trayIcon.Icon = new Icon("C:\\Users\\Name\\Desktop\\test.ico", 40, 40); //origin, width, height

        trayIcon.ContextMenu = trayMenu;

        trayIcon.BalloonTipTitle = "MyTitle";
        trayIcon.BalloonTipText = "This is sample message ";
        trayIcon.ShowBalloonTip(30000);
        trayIcon.Visible = true;
    }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        Visible = false; // Hide form window.
        ShowInTaskbar = false; // Remove from taskbar.

        base.OnLoad(e);
    }

    private void OnExit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool isDisposing)
    {
        if (isDisposing)
        {
            // Release the icon resource.
            trayIcon.Dispose();
        }

        base.Dispose(isDisposing);
    }

}
```

It is displaying Icon in taskbar, but not showing notification.
My requirement is same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15215716/2689414).

Comment: Did you try to move ShowBalloonTip() after Visible = true?

Comment: I traied, but no use @AdrianoRepetti

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to show a message with icon in notification are using C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15215716/how-to-show-a-message-with-icon-in-notification-are-using-c-sharp)

Comment: Sorry @AdrianoRepetti. I tried first. But i donno, on that time it didn't worked.

Comment: in my case it was working until I added `SystemSounds.Beep.Play()` then notification balloon **NEVER** showed up again, regardless of the code. I have tried any sample code on line and none worked again. Restarted VS, created new solution, restarted windows, etc, to no avail.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that the code that shows the BallonTip resides in the constructor of the form. You must place the **ShowBallonTip()** call in a method that runs after that the form is *'costructed'*.

Comment: Ok... I think it's right the answer given by Luis Teixeira.