# WPF C# hide Console application Show Icon in Hidden task bar

Tags: c#, wpf, console, hide

I´m using C#, I want to hide the console application but I want to show the icon in "hidden taskbar" (I don´t know if it is the correct name), something similar like Thunderbird, Team Viewer....

[image]

I´ve tried this:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

const int SW_HIDE = 0;
const int SW_SHOWMINIMIZED = 2;
const int SW_SHOW = 5;
const int SW_MINIMIZE = 6;

private const string AppGuid = "c0a76b5a-12ab-45c5-b9d9-d693faa6e7b9";

// ==============================
// ==============================

var handle = GetConsoleWindow();
ShowWindow(handle, SW_HIDE);
```

But If I hide the console it is not shown in the "Hidden Task Bar". Is it posible to hide the console and show in the "Hidden Task Bar"?

Comment: What do you mean with "console application"? Another app or the taskbar icon of your WPF app?

Comment: My project in C# is Visual C# -> Console Application. I write in the console some information. I´ve updated a picture like example, in the picture thunderbid, team viewer are in the "hidden taskbar"

Comment: I'm confused: you said you are using WPF...

Comment: Sorry, I always use WPF, but this is not a WPF application, is a Console application. Now edit the post.

Comment: This link is about WinForms, but the concepts are similar
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995195/how-can-i-make-a-net-windows-forms-application-that-only-runs-in-the-system-tra

Answer (score 0):

the keyword which you must search for is "notification icon", then you will find something like [How to show a message with icon in the notification area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15215716/how-to-show-a-message-with-icon-in-the-notification-area)
i can not explain it more precise because i don't know whether you are using wpf or a console application