# C# Windows Forms App - Show balloon tip

Tags: c#, balloon-tip

I try to show a balloon tip like the one in the screenshot:

[image]

First I created a notifyIcon

[image]

Then I added this code to the **Form1_Load** function:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    notifyIcon1.Visible = true;
    notifyIcon1.Icon = SystemIcons.Exclamation;
    notifyIcon1.BalloonTipTitle = "Balloon Tip Title";
    notifyIcon1.BalloonTipText = "Balloon Tip Text.";
    notifyIcon1.BalloonTipIcon = ToolTipIcon.Error;
    notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(10000);
}
```

All I get is a little icon, and If I hover over it then i see the name of the notify icon.
[image]

I also tried this `notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(10000, "Text", "Title", ToolTipIcon.Warning);` but then nothing happens.

I noticed in the function description of `ShowBalloonTip`, that the parameter "timeout" is deprecated from windows vista on, so what should I do instead?

PS: I run it on windows 10 64bit.

---

**UPDATE 1/3:**

I just created a fresh project, the balloon tip does not show either.
Maybe a setting in my OS blocks these messages?

**UPDATE 2/3:**

I downloaded the project from [@pisi1001](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3734638/pisi1001) but I get the same behaviour.

So I think it must be either a bug in windows 10, a wrong setting or group policy.

However like the next screenshots shows, the app is even allowed to show notifications:

[image]
[image]

**UPDATE 3/3:**

I noticed that you can even configure deeper if you double click on the setting, e.g. on "WindowsFormsApp1" from the last screenshot.

[image]

After I activated the setting in the red box in the last screenshot (which is basically saying "Show Notifications in the Info Center") I get at least notifications in the info center now:

[image]

This must be a Windows 10 Bug.

**LAST UPDATE**: A few weeks passed since I asked this question, now it seems to work and I am not sure why. Maybe Microsoft fixed it after I reported it to them.

Comment: Are you sure you're not looking for the `notifyIcon1.Text` property? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon.icon(v=vs.110).aspx close to the end of the Form1() constructor.

Comment: Nvm. the `.Text` property will just put the change in your last picture but not what you want which is your first picture.

Comment: I try the same like in this question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15215716/how-to-show-a-message-with-icon-in-the-notification-area) but the solutions from there are not working for me.

Comment: No, there is only a warning because of my onedrive being full.